# Events from COM: works fine in WinForms/WPF but doesn't work in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, com, interop, sta

Please tell me why does the following work fine in WinForms/WPF and not in ASP.Net.

We have a class library targeted for .Net 3.5. It has an interop referenced (generated from TLB).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(string newStatus);
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

    private ComObject objCom = new ComObject();

    public void Init()
    {
        //Com events.
        objCom.AvailabilityChanged += objCom_AvailabilityChanged;

        //Start session to the h/w device.
        //When finished, AvailabilityChanged event is fired with new h/w status.
        objCom.StartSession("DeviceName");
    }

    void objCom_AvailabilityChanged(ComStatus status)
    {
        //Fired when session is started.
        Changed(status.ToString());
    }

}
```

And then i have a WinForms/WPF application (targeted for .Net 4.5) that creates a new instance of MyClass, subscribes to the Changed event and calls Init().
This works perfectly.

I'm trying to do the same in ASP.Net web forms application. The Init() method is being called, but the objCom_AvailabilityChanged event in MyClass is never fired.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MyClass test = new MyClass();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.Changed += test_Changed;
        test.Init();
    }

    void test_Changed(string newStatus)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = newStatus;
    }
}
```

Please explain what am i doing wrong.

Thanks a lot!